# OnTapped / OnClicked on the HubSections Header

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have HubSection which looks like:

```
<HubSection Header="Press to me >">
   <DataTemplate>
   ...
   </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

I am wondering if there is any way to process tap/click event on the Header of HubSection ("press me >") ?

Comment: [Hub.SectionHeaderClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.sectionheaderclick.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please post it as answer and I close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickie answers like this almost feel non deserving of the points but...

You're just looking for [Hub.SectionHeaderClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.sectionheaderclick.aspx) event. Should also point out you'll need to set your [HubSection.IsHeaderInteractive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hubsection.isheaderinteractive.aspx) bool property to `True` to enable it.

Hope this helps, cheers!